# Definite integral from $0$ to $t$ of $t$ wrt. $s$

Tags: calculus, integration

Alright, so this is something I should know, but have forgotten. Doing it straightforward, I can come up with this:
$$\int_0^t t \,\mathrm{d} s= t^2$$
I can't shake the feeling that this is wrong, however.

Comment: What makes you think it is wrong?

Comment: The fact that my textbook seems to think the answer is t^2/2.

Comment: It may just be then that there is a type in your textbook, and that $ds$ term should be a $dt$. I would advise against such use of notation (t as the integration variable and t into in limits of the integral) as this is more confusing than anything for starters.

Comment: No, the integral is correct, it's part of a recursion for approximating a DE and this is the first recursion, and the answer is off by a factor of 2. I'm gonna blame the editors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\int_0^tt\,ds=t\color{blue}{\int_0^tds}=t\color{blue}{s\Big|_0^t}=t\left(t-0\right)=t^2.
$$

Answer (score 2):

That looks correct.

You feel suspicious, because textbook problems tend to be biased away from "overly simple" problems like this, which unfortunately teaches you that problems can't be simple.

(but, to be fair, there are only so many ways you can ask "what is the integral of a constant?")

These things, however, *do* come up often enough in real world problems.

Comment: Or even more likely: in future mathematics problems. Like multiple integrals :)